# CMake - Automatically Parsing Dependencies of Precompiled Header?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake

As of yet, at least to my knowledge, there is no standard way in CMake to specify the addition of a precompiled header (PCH) to a project in a cross-platform manner because the way PCHs are handled by C++ compilers is very different among vendors. For G++, this is usually this is worked around by simply adding a *custom command* which takes care of invoking the compiler with the appropriate input and has it generate the PCH.

My current problem is that CMake will not parse the dependencies of the dependencies you specify for the custom command. For instance, assume the following structure:

```
pch.h
 |- dependA.h
 |- dependB.h
 ...
```

Only providing `pch.h` as a dependency will lead to the generation of the appropriate target in the corresponding `makefile`, which tracks changes to `pch.h`. However, CMake does not parse the includes *inside* `pch.h` and will therefore not recognize changes to `dependA.h` and `dependB.h`. This extends furhter if there are dependencies for `dependsA.h` and so on.

**Note**: I'm aware that the fact that PCH dependencies can and do change regularly puts the whole process in question. However, this is just the way it is and I can't really do anything about it.

Since the task isn't too hard, there are a couple of obvious ideas that come to mind:

**Solution A:**

Enter all the dependencies by hand. Obviously this works, but is tedious as hell and doesn't scale at all.

**Solution B:**

If possible, write a CMake function that automates the process and parse the includes "manually".

**Solution C:**

Do something similar using a different language, for instance Python, and just provide CMake a list of dependencies to add to the custom command.

**Solution D:**

Use `gcc`/`g++`'s feature to parse and print out the dependency tree of the PCH and parse the output to extract the list of dependencies.

My question is: does anyone know a more convenient and faster way to get this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IMPLICIT_DEPENDS` option of the [add_custom_command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command) might do the trick:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT outFile
    COMMAND ...
    IMPLICIT_DEPENDS CXX "pch.h")
```

The `IMPLICIT_DEPENDS` option makes the generated build system scan the implicit dependencies of the given input file at build time. It is only supported for Makefile generators, though.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try. It's a shame it won't work with Ninja though.

Comment: Do you know if the "dependency scanner" is implemented by make or can it be used in cmake code to get the included files and add them manually as dependencies?